# Network Booting Raspberry Pi 2 from a Virtual Machine?

Tags: pi-2, networking, boot

I have to do this for a school project, and since I was unsure on how to proceed, i thought I might ask you people for assisstance.

Originally I was following [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes), but once I poked around a bit I realised that the Pi I was working on was a 2, not a 3. I then proceeded to follow [this guide](https://youresuchageek.blogspot.com/2013/01/raspberrypi-root-over-nfs-share.html), but am currently stuck on Step 2.

As you can no doubt infer from my issue, I am a complete and total beginner at working with Linux distributions, and Linux-based OSes in general.

My current setup is:

- A Raspberry Pi 2 with the latest Jessie distribution image, with a NOOBS installer (client)
- An instance of Ubuntu Server running on WMware Workstation 12 (Server)

Additional information which might be useful:

- The network I am currently connecting the two through ethernet on has a firewall; A log-in is required to access anything outside of the intranet.
- The Pi's Micro-SD Card is not large enough to hold two copies of the same filesystem/kernel (I am unsure as to the actual size of the card, packaging displays 8gb but Raspbian displays ~5gb)

How would I proceed with this operation? As I said, I am an unsure beginner when working with Linux distributions, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

If you are interest in **[virtual machine for Raspberry Pi](https://eltechs.com/exagear-desktop-virtual-machine-for-raspberry-pi/?utm_source=raspberrypi_stackexchange&utm_medium=exagear-desktop-virtual-machine-for-raspberry-pi&utm_campaign=forum_self-linking)** - follow the link

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.